# Detecting python exceptions in Node child_process

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn

I've noticed that when I spawn a python script in Node.js using the `child_process` spawn() method, I can't catch exceptions.

Here's a simple example to illustrate:

index.js:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

(() => {
    const py = spawn('python', ['../pyfun/main.py']);

    py.stdout.on('data', function(data){
        console.log(data.toString());
    });

    py.stdout.on('end', function(){
        console.log('Finished');
    });

    py.stdout.on('error', function(){
        console.log('* Error');
    });

    py.on('error', (err) => {
        console.error('**', err);
    });

    py.stderr.on('error', (err) => {
        console.log('*** Error', error);
    })
})();
```

main.py:

```
def main():
    print('Hello')
    raise ValueError('Python Error')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output is

```
Hello // <-- from python

Finished // <-- from Node
```

I'm getting the `hello` from the Python script, but I'm unable to pick up the error. This is also the case if I use `raise Exception('error')` in the python script too.

Any insight appreciated.

Comment: Add a handler for `py.on('exit', code => {})` and if the code is nonzero, the error has been dumped to stderr which you can access via `py.stderr.on('data', data => {})`

Comment: Thanks, adding 'stderr.on('data'... worked. If you add that as an answer I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: Glad it worked! I'll do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a handler for `py.on('exit', code => {})` and if the code is nonzero, the error has been dumped to stderr which you can access via `py.stderr.on('data', data => {})`